# Python dictionary add/delete items in tkinter versus non-GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to implement a primitive dictionary to look up acronyms that we use in the laboratory. The dictionary is in the format:

```
{'REN': 'plasma renin', 'PROP': 'procollagen III', 'IMETAB': 'intermediary metabolites, pyruvate, lactate, beta-OH-butyrate'...}
```

I can do a search items on the dictionary both in the GUI and the other format, but get an error when trying to add/delete items but only with the GUI format.
Here are the two snippets of offending code :

This code works

```
elif inp == 'add':
        abbr_in = input('acronym: ')
        text_in = input('expanded text: ')
        acronyms[abbr_in] = text_in
        with open('acronym_dict.py','w')as outfile:
            outfile.write(str(acronyms))
            outfile.close()

elif inp == 'delete':
         name = input("Enter acronym to delete: ").upper()
         r =dict(acronyms)

          del r[name]                 

            with open('acronym_dict.py','w')as outfile:
                outfile.write(str(r))
                outfile.close()
```

and the GUI code which does not work:

```
def add_acronym(): 
add_del_acronym.get()
add_del_acronym.upper()
abbr_in = addordel_acronym
add_expansion.get()
text_in = add_expansion
acronyms[abbr_in] = text_in
# write amended dictionary
with open('acronym_dict.py','w')as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(acronyms))
    outfile.close()
def remove_acronym():
    name = addordel_acronym.get().upper()
    name.upper()
    r =dict(acronyms)
    del r[name] 
    # write amended dictionary   
    with open('acronym_dict.py','w')as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(r))
        outfile.close()
```

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Please could someone come to my assistance. Do not understand what to do.
Thanks

Comment: your indentation is messed up in your example making it impossible to know the true nature of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you give has nothing to do with tkinter. When you get an error message that says:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

... then it means you are calling a function  like `something.get()` but you've defined something as `def something(self)`. So, track down which function call is throwing this error to find your problem. My guess is that you have some variable that you *think* is a dictionary but is actually an instance of a class.

Based on the comments to the original version of this question, it appears that you are incorrectly using the tkinter `StringVar` class. You apparently are doing this:

```
variable = tkinter.StringVar
```

This causes you to assign a *class* to `variable` rather than an *instance* of the class to `variable`. The class defines a method named `get` which you are calling, but it requires the `self` parameter which tells the class which instance you are referring to. Since you aren't referring to an instance, `self` is undefined and thus you get the error that you report.

To fix your problem you must create an instance of `StringVar`, like so:

```
variable = tkinter.StringVar()
```

Comment: I cannot see it. Is there any 'quick' way to find an error like this. Can't think of a unittest or doctest. Any suggestions? Should I post the whole code?

Comment: @user1478335: The "quick" way is to look at the full text of the error, it should tell you the line number that is causing the problem.

Comment: Moved on I commented out everything except the variable.get() and added a print(variable). As you said, its a class. I get the message <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>
How do I deal with this to get a value ?

Comment: @user1478335: if it is printing `<class 'tkinter.StringVar'`, then it is a _class_ rather than an _instance_ of a class. Since there's no place in the code in your question where you use `StringVar`, I can only guess that you're doing something like `variable=tkinter.StringVar` when you should be doing `variable=tkinter.StringVar()` (note the trailing parenthesis)

Comment: OK Problem solved, but it has highlighted something that I am not clear about.For add/delete I was calling the textvariable 'name' and not the 'name of the Entry box. By using the name of the Entry, the problem has been solved. However in other parts such as find, I have had to use textvariable name to establish equality. When does one make a call using these two? I am not sure if my question is clear - I know what I mean! acronym_edit =Entry(f2,textvariable=edit_acronym, style =".TEntry") I was using edit_acronym, but now am using acronym_edit to resolve the problem

Comment: @user1478335: If you have another question, please post it as a question rather than as a comment to an answer.